# Download multiple files in same record from a database table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, file-upload, webforms

I have this table to store Purchase Order data, it can hold up to 3 files (first file is required, second and third is optional) which their column names are highlighted in the picture.

[image]

I have already done the Upload page, which save all the data entered and uploaded by user to the database, it is working fine, I can see all the saved file names and bytes in the table.

I am working on the View page, which retrieve data from database and display it to the webpage and **have problem of retrieving the files**.

The idea is to display the file name to the page (which is working fine) and when user click onto the file name, they can save it to the computer (or open/run etc depend on web browser prompt windows), **problem here is that**: **I can only save the first file**, when clicking on the second and third file name, nothing happened although when in debugging mode they (name, type and data of file2 and file3) do exist but the prompt windows to save file is not appeared

Any idea how to fix this or if anyone have better method of how to download these files please help.

Here is my code (please ignore the unrelated codes or please let me know if you want to know what they do):

The View.aspx to display file names

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtPOFile" runat="server" OnClick="lbtPOFile_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtPOFile2" runat="server" OnClick="lbtPOFile2_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtPOFile3" runat="server"  OnClick="lbtPOFile3_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
```

C# behind: the DownloadFile() method has 3 parameters, they are just column names in the database table, corresponding to the file1, file2 or file3, it supposes to retrieve the file when user click onto the file name (called in the click events below)

```
protected void DownloadFile(string fileNameColumn, string fileTypeColumn, string fileDataColumn)
    {
        string guid = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["guid"]) ? Request.QueryString["guid"] : Guid.Empty.ToString();
        string id = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["id"]) ? Request.QueryString["id"] : "0";

        if (requestDAL.ValidatePODetailLink(guid, Convert.ToInt32(id)))
        {
            byte[] bytes = null;
            string fileName = "";
            string contentType = "";

            DataTable PODetail = requestDAL.GetPODetail(guid, Convert.ToInt32(id));
            foreach (DataRow row in PODetail.Rows)
            {
                bytes = (byte[])row[fileDataColumn];
                contentType = row[fileTypeColumn].ToString();
                fileName = row[fileNameColumn].ToString();
            }
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.ContentType = contentType;
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
            Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }

        else
        {
            //Display message
            InfoPanel.Visible = true;
            lblMessage.Text = "<b>Invalid file or an error has occurred while connecting to the database. Please try again later!</b>";
            lblMessage.CssClass = "text text-danger bold";
            InfoPanel.CssClass = "panel panel-danger";
            FormPanel.Visible = false;
            FormPanel.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

protected void lbtPOFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DownloadFile("poFileName", "poFileContentType", "poFileData");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Display message
            InfoPanel.Visible = true;
            lblMessage.Text = "<b>An error has occurred. Please try again later!</b></br>" + ex.Message;
            lblMessage.CssClass = "text text-danger bold";
            InfoPanel.CssClass = "panel panel-danger";
            FormPanel.Visible = false;
            FormPanel.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    protected void lbtPOFile2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DownloadFile("poFileName2", "poFileContentType2", "poFileData2");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Display message
            InfoPanel.Visible = true;
            lblMessage.Text = "<b>An error has occurred. Please try again later!</b></br>" + ex.Message;
            lblMessage.CssClass = "text text-danger bold";
            InfoPanel.CssClass = "panel panel-danger";
            FormPanel.Visible = false;
            FormPanel.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    protected void lbtPOFile3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DownloadFile("poFileName3", "poFileContentType3", "poFileData3");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Display message
            InfoPanel.Visible = true;
            lblMessage.Text = "<b>An error has occurred. Please try again later!</b></br>" + ex.Message;
            lblMessage.CssClass = "text text-danger bold";
            InfoPanel.CssClass = "panel panel-danger";
            FormPanel.Visible = false;
            FormPanel.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

Some related functions in case you need it:

```
// Validate link for employee (link format is View.aspx?guid=xxx&id=xxx)
    public static bool ValidatePODetailLink(string guid, int poID)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            string query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PO WHERE poID = @poID AND poGUID = @guid";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@guid", guid);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@poID", poID);
            con.Open();
            int i = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            if (i == 1) return true;
            else return false;
        }
    }

    //Get po request details for employee
    public static DataTable GetPODetail(string guid, int poID)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            string query = "SELECT * FROM PO WHERE poID = @poID AND poGUID = @guid";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@guid", guid);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@poID", poID);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }
    }
```

**PROBLEM FOUND:**
I use `UpdatePanel` and only put `<Triggers> <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="lbtPOFile" /> </Triggers>` hence it was missing `PostBackTrigger` for **lbtPOFile2** and **lbtPOFile3**. Added those 2 lines and it works.

Comment: Why did you use a foreach if you only want to get one file??? Also, maybe if you post the C# code of the lbtPOFile2_Click and DownloadFile2 we could find something

Comment: @EnriqueZavaleta Updated! added codes. The reason I don't use foreach or other method is that: the code for downloading the first file worked w/o any problem so when it comes to the second and third file, I just go ahead and copy paste, change the name to see if it work, and it doesn't.

Comment: I'm not asking why not use it a foreach, I'm asking why you have one in your code, look: foreach (DataRow row in PODetail.Rows)

Comment: @EnriqueZavaleta Correct me if I was wrong, I wanted to loop through all rows in PODetail.Rows, find the correct rows (by name) that I need and return (assign) data in those rows to bytes, contentType and fileName variable?

Comment: If first work and others don't, this might be a copy/paste error.

Comment: @AXMIM Yes, it pretty much was. I use `UpdatePanel` and only put `<Triggers> <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="lbtPOFile" /> </Triggers>` hence it was missing `PostBackTrigger` for `lbtPOFile2` and `lbtPOFile3`. Added those 2 lines and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest the following approach.

1. Revert your code to the "known good" state (where it can only handle the download of one file, but does so correctly)
2. Refactor this code so that it still supports a single file download.  Take the code that streams the file contents into the response; move it into a separate function (perhaps call this `SendFile`); call that function from your click handler; recompile and confirm that everything is still working.
3. Now modify `SendFile` so that it accepts input parameters that determine whether it will return file 1, file 2, or file 3.  Modify the click handler so that it passes the parameters that indicate file 1.  Recompile and test again, make sure it still works.
4. Now add two additional click handlers for your other two link buttons.  Should be identical to your existing click handler except for the arguments that are passed to `SendFile`.  Recompile and test with all three files.

Comment: 1. It still works and always work on the first file, I can only download the first file no matter what.
2 - 3 -4 I edit my answer, using one method and passing parameter to it to determine which file should be downloaded but problem remain the same, I can only download the first file.

Comment: OK found the problem:  I use `UpdatePanel` and only put `<Triggers>
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="lbtPOFile" />
        </Triggers>` hence it was missing `PostBackTrigger` for `lbtPOFile2` and `lbtPOFile3`. Added those 2 lines and it works. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Glad you found the issue.  Hopefully my suggestion at least helped to isolate the problem.